# Loop through fields of recordset to populate form?

Tags: forms, vba, loops, recordset

I'm trying to use a For loop to loop through the fields in a single record recordset to populate the fields on a form. I was hoping to find a way that is neater/reusable than typing out half a dozen lines of txtField.value = rs!Field.

When I look at the code during runtime both variables have the correct information in them, it just isn't displaying them on the form. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Dim strClient As String
Dim rsClient As dao.Recordset
Dim tfield As String
Dim ffiend As String
Dim fld As dao.Field

Set dbs_Current = CurrentDb()

strClient = "Select * from tblClient where pk_client_id = " & gbl_Client_ID

Set rsClient = dbs_Current.OpenRecordset(strClient)

For Each fld In rsClient.Fields
    On Error Resume Next
    tfield = "txt" & fld.Name & ".value"
    ffield = "rsClient!" & fld.Name
    tfield = ffield

Next fld
```

Comment: You're never actually adding the value to a field / control on the form. Look at the `Controls` collection object of the form.

Comment: Thanks, I've got it now. I was looking at it from the wrong 'angle'.